# algorithm verifying data from user beween two tables then insert into another table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Greeting I need to get details from users, in those details the user has I have to validate all the User details validate this details with another table and if the date doesn’t match insert on the table but if it does match then don insert anything, this has to be done for all the users, the domains.

```
User{
String orderNumber
String dealer
Int UserKm
String dateUser
String adviser
Vehicle vehicle
String dateCreated

Date appointmentDate //this date has to be validated with DateNext 
appointmentDate from Appointments domain of it doesn’t exit then you can 
insert on that table.

}
Appointments{
User user
Date managementDate
Date lasDataApointies
DateNext appointmentDate
Date NextdAteAppointment
Date callDate
String observations
}

def result = User.executeQuery("""select new map( 
mmt.id as id, mmt.orderNumber as orderNumber, mmt.dealer.dealer as 
dealer, mmt.UserKm as UserKm, mmt.dateUser as dateUser, mmt.adviser as 
adviser, mmt.technician as technician, mmt.vehicle.placa as vehicle, 
mmt.dateCreated as dateCreated, mmt.currenKm as currenKm) from User as 
mmt """)

def result1=result.groupBy{it.vehicle}

List detailsReslt=[]

result1?.each { SlasDataApointing placa, listing ->
def firsT = listing.first()

int firstKM = firsT.UserKm

def lasT = listing.last()
def lasDataApoint = lasT.id

int lastKM = lasT.UserKm

int NextAppointmentKM = lastKM + 5000

int dayBetweenLastAndNext = lastKM - NextAppointmentKM

def tiDur = getDifference(firsT.dateUser,lasT.dateUser)
int dayToInt = tiDur.days

int restar = firstKM - lastKM

int kmPerDay = restar.div(dayToInt)
int nextMaintenaceDays = dayBetweenLastAndNext.div(kmPerDay)

def nextAppointment = lasT.dateUser + nextMaintenaceDays            
detailsReslt<<[placa:placa, nextAppointment: 
nextAppointment, manageId:lasDataApoint, nextKmUser: NextAppointmentKM]
        }

detailsReslt?.each {
Appointments addUserData = new Appointments()
addUserData.User = User.findById(it.manageId)
addUserData.managementDate = null
addUserData.NextdAteAppointment = null
addUserData.observations = null
addUserData.callDate = it.nextAppointment
addUserData.save(flush: true)
}

 println "we now have ${detailsReslt}"
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the logic you are trying to  implement but I would suggest creating a grails service class and start writing some code to manipulate the entities you have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details that are not full and looking at the code I can suggest:
no need to do a query to map you can simply query the list of users and check all the properties like `user.vehicle`. in any case, you need to check each row.
the groupBy{it.vehicle} is not clear but if needed you can do it using ***createCriteria projections "groupProperty"***

1. Create 2 service method one for iterating all users and one for each user:

   ```
   validateAppointment(User user){
       /* your validation logic */
       ....
      if (validation term){
      Appointments addUserData = new Appointments()
      ...
      }
   }
   validateAppointments(){
       List users = User. list()
       users.each{User user
       validateAppointment(user)
       }
   }
   ```
2. you can trigger the **validateAppointments** service from anywhere in the code or create a scheduled job so it will run automatically based on your needs.
3. if your list of user is big and also for efficiency you can do bulk update - take a look at my post about it: https://medium.com/meni-lubetkin/grails-bulk-updates-4d749f24cba1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a Custom Validator using a Service, something like this:

```
class User{

    def appointmentService

    ...    
    Date appointmentDate

    static constraints = {
        appointmentDate validator: { val, obj ->
            obj.appointmentService.isDateAppointmentValid(obj.appointmentDate)
        }
    }

}
```

But keep in mind that validation may run more often than you think. It is triggered by the `validate()` and `save()` methods as you’d expect (as explained in the [user guide (v3.1.15)](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.15/guide/single.html)). So I'm not sure if this scenario is the best way to validate àppointmentDate` in your domain, so you have to be careful about that.

Hope this help.